# NullPointerException when executing rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryData)

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, sap-ase

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase ASE database. When I retrieve data I get NullPointerException on `rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryData);`.
I tried the same query with dbVisualizer but everything is ok there.

```
static void retrieveData() {
   try {
       String queryData="SELECT * FROM med WHERE item_id like 'A00001'";
       // process the results.
       rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryData);
       while (rs.next()) {
            String s = rs.getString("item_naam");
            String n = rs.getString("item_mnemo");
            System.out.println(s + "   " + n);
       }
   }catch(SQLException ex) {
       System.err.println("RetrieveData: " + ex.getMessage()+ " sqlstate = " +
                ex.getSQLState());
       System.exit(1);
   }
```

Comment: where do you initialize stmt?

Comment: I have a similar problem ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417987/null-pointer-exception-when-trying-resultset-rs-stmt-executequeryexecute#comment99431727_56417987 Can you help me maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seem to be that `stmt` is not initialized, i assume that you at least have defined the variable `stmt`, cause if not, the developer environment would show an error.

There are lot of NullpointerExceptions caused for not initializing a variable, i mean you define it and then you forget to initialize it, its a good advice (if you dont have memory problems and you are opften to forget to init the variables) to do both things simultaneously.

yo can do:

```
 Statement s = c.createStatement();
  rs = s.executeQuery(queryData);
```

and remember that **c where previoulsy initialized and rs was defined before**...

Comment: Thanks a lot i did as below:
`try {
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,      password);
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println("Connection has been established");
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.err.println("database connection: " + ex.getMessage()+"SQLState: "+ex.getSQLState());
     }`

Answer (score 4):

The `stmt` object is probably not initialized.

Comment: I did in the top of class as below:
`public class BcfiConnection {
    static Connection con;
    static Statement stmt;
    static ResultSet rs;`

Comment: That's declaration, not initialization. You need to create a connection and then use it to create the statement.